# What is a good way to sort two log files as they are created?

Tags: logs, sort

I have two scripts running, both of which output a log file.  I'd like to make a third script that can sort these logs by time stamp and merge them into one file as they are created.  What is a good way to do this, ideally without overwriting the file constantly?

Comment: Does it have to be a logfile, or can you instead call `logger(1)` and let the syslog daemon handle the getting-the-data-to-a-file part?

Comment: If they output in append mode, as with a `>>` redirection, (and whole lines/entries at a time), you can just point them to the same file and get the output in the order it was generated.

Comment: sort cannot finish until its input is closed. You'll need to repeatedly {open and read the 2 input files, sort and write}

Comment: Ditto what Glenn said. You can't, generally speaking.

Comment: Does each logging process always output its own messages in the right order?  Does it print new messages immediately (always with the current time), or does it buffer messages for a while (sometimes printing timestamps after they happened)?

Comment: @Kathy this is what databses were invented for. ;-)

Comment: This isn't a full _sort_. It's actually a _merge sort_ on two already sorted streams. Therefore the tool - whatever it might be - doesn't need to read the entire input before merging. (Think back to your computer science algorithm days...)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `tail -f` to tail 2 or more files, then the command shows the data line-by-line, and outputs the filename each time the source of data changes.
Using this you can write a script to merge the interleaved output from tail according to timestamp by holding onto each line until you see a line from the other file with a later timestamp.

For example, using two standard logfiles (`/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/cron`) which on my system have the same format for the timestamp at the start of the line (eg `Jun  9 02:55:01`), you can do the following:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages /var/log/cron |
awk '
BEGIN { num[0] = 0; num[1] = 0; }
/^==> /{
  file = $2; aa = file~/messages/?0:1; bb = 1-aa; 
  aanum = num[aa]; bbnum = num[bb];
  next }
/^$/{ next }
{ "date --date \"" $1 " " $2 " " $3 "\" +%s" | getline date
  lines[aa,aanum] = $0
  dates[aa,aanum++] = date
  maxes[aa] = date
  minmax = maxes[aa]
  if(maxes[bb]<minmax)minmax = maxes[bb]

  i = 0; j = 0;
  while(1){
    aaok = (i<aanum && dates[aa,i]<=minmax)
    bbok = (j<bbnum && dates[bb,j]<=minmax)
    if(aaok && bbok){
      if(dates[aa,i]<=dates[bb,j]){
           print lines[aa,i]; dates[aa,i++] = ""
      }else{
           print lines[bb,j]; dates[bb,j++] = ""
      }
    }else if(aaok){
           print lines[aa,i]; dates[aa,i++] = ""
    }else if(bbok){
           print lines[bb,j]; dates[bb,j++] = ""
    }else break
  }
  i = 0
  for(j = 0; j<aanum;j++)
    if(dates[aa,j]!=""){
      dates[aa,i] = dates[aa,j]; lines[aa,i++] = lines[aa,j]
    }
  aanum = num[aa] = i
  i = 0
  for(j = 0; j<bbnum;j++)
    if(dates[bb,j]!=""){
      dates[bb,i] = dates[bb,j]; lines[bb,i++] = lines[bb,j]
    }
  bbnum = num[bb] = i
}'
```

The awk flips between the 2 files when it sees the `==>` file heading from tail. It keeps data, in 4 arrays, separately for each file, arbitrarily called `aa` and `bb` and numbered 0 and 1. `dates` holds the timestamp (in seconds from the epoch), `lines` holds the input log line, `num` holds the count of lines, and `maxes` the highest date for a file. The first 2 arrays are 2-dimensional indexed by file (0 or 1) and count of held lines.

As each log line is read, the timestamp is converted to seconds, and saved in a new entry at the end of `dates`, and the line is saved too. The minimum of the current two dates is set in `minmax`. The whole held data is scanned and printed according to timestamp order upto this minimum. Printed entries are cleared, and at the end of the while loop, the arrays are squashed to remove these cleared entries.

Answer (score 0):

Given the assumptions that the log files have the same source of timestamps, that each log is written in time order at the time the log entry is created, and that the timestamp leads the line, you can do something as simple as this:

```
tail -qF log1 log2 > summarylog
```

If the assumptions don't hold for your situation, please update your question to provide clarification and examples.